# Многосайтовость

Tags: битрикс

Есть созданный поддомен на timeweb, как в Битрикс сделать новый сайт, чтобы он стал основным для поддомена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ядро (папка `bitrix`) и папку `upload` выносишь в отдельную папку (к примеру shared), и симлинком подключаешь к двум свои сайтам, один который на поддомене, второй, который основной. Затем в настройках  `Настройки > Настройки продукта > Сайты > Список сайтов` настраиваешь свои два сайта (указываешь его параметры и там все приоритеты можешь настроить).

Больше информации на сайте Битрикс https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=103&LESSON_ID=287&LESSON_PATH=8799.3987.287